# SQL MAX expression Function

Tags: sql, max, netezza

In a SQL statement I need to select the expression as

```
SELECT maxValues AS MAX(MIN(100,x),50)
```

Where x is a result of another complex SQL query. Basically in the place of x I have another SQl select statement.

If I execute the above expression using select statement, I get the following error.

> ERROR [42000] ERROR:  'maxValues as max(min(100,x),50)'
>        nullerror                         'EXCEPT' or 'FOR' or 'INTERSECT' or 'ORDER' or 'UNION'

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please paste your full SQL code.

Comment: Min and Max accept one argument

Comment: Where do I post my code?

Answer (score 1):

Use `GREATEST` and `LEAST` rather than `MAX` and `MIN`

GREATEST and LEAST give you the greatest and least values from a list of values whereas MAX and MIN give you the maximum and minimum values in a column.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a transaction that declares a variable to transfer your value from one query to the next

```
DECLARE
V_X NUMBER;
V_RESULT NUMBER;
V_SQL_1 CLOB := "_QUERY 1_";

BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE V_SQL_1 INTO V_X;

  SELECT MAX(MIN(100,V_X),50) INTO V_RESULT FROM DUAL;

END
```

(This assumes oracle-SQL.)

Comment: I'm using IBM Neteeza. In Neteeza I can't use DECLARE variable or use Code block like this. I can only use normal SQL or CASE.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with a `CASE`:

```
SELECT maxValues AS CASE when x > 100 then 100
                         when x < 50 then 50
                         else x end
```

(If supported... I don't know IBM Neteeza.)